# Can I change fault injection configuration envoy proxy at run-time?

Tags: envoyproxy

I understand that I can configure fault injection in Envoy proxy with the bellow configuration.

config.filter.http.fault.v2.FaultAbort

```
{
  "http_status": "...",
  "percentage": "{...}"
}
```

The above code will fail the specified percentage of the requests with the specified http_status, for instance 500.

Now, can I change it at runtime? I would like to insert a fault against a specific service, say, for 10 seconds and then put it back to normal. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can change things like this in Envoy during operation through one of two mechanisms:

1. [Hot Restart](https://blog.envoyproxy.io/envoy-hot-restart-1d16b14555b5)
2. [Sending Dynamic Configs with xDS](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-docs/xds_protocol)

The hot restart mechanism is much simpler for small deployments, so if this is a small effort or test I would recommend that.

The xDS option is basically to create a central server that the Envoy proxy connects to.  This server then sends all configurations to the proxy however you want.  This is far more complicated (needing to create user-interfaces, default configs, service discovery, etc etc etc) but provides many benefits which is why companies and projects have sprung up with their own implementations.